Escaping closed <> in Github Markdown
I'm sure this is an easy question and I'm just missing it somewhere in the documentation, but I haven't had much luck on my own.
I'm looking write some documentation for a series of variable names in a workflow I'm developing, but I can't get some of the characters I need to escape correctly in the markdown.
What I need is something along the lines literal strings of:

Occur<x>_<CON/VAR1/VAR2>
Covariate<x>_<CON/VAR1/VAR2>

But if I type this out literally in the git markdown with relevant escape characters for the _:
Occur<x>\_<CON/VAR1/VAR2>
Covariate<x>\_<CON/VAR1/VAR2>

I get:

Occur_
Covariate_

In the markdown.
Similarly, if I attempt to escape all of the > and < characters:
Occur\<x\>\_\<CON/VAR1/VAR2\>
Covariate\<x\>\_\<CON/VAR1/VAR2\>

I get:

Occur_
Covariate_

as well.
However, if I do:
Occur\<\x\>\_\<\CON/VAR1/VAR2\>
Covariate\<\x\>\_\<\CON/VAR1/VAR2\>

I ALMOST get the desired output:

Occur<\x>_<\CON/VAR1/VAR2>
Covariate<\x>_<\CON/VAR1/VAR2>

With the exception of the back slash in front of the other strings.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might be able to format this correctly?

What about HTML entities? &lt; for < and &gt; for >. So you'd write Occur_&lt;CON/VAR1/VAR2&gt;.

Tried the following, based on what it was supposed to be in the original posting:
Occur&lt;x&gt;\_&lt;CON/VAR1/VAR2&gt;
Got this:
Occur_

Not a git question

What @eftshift0 said. It looks like you have maxed out on the number of tags that you can use without considering if they are relevant. Your question won’t have a higher likelihood of being answered just because you use as many tags as you can.

@eftshift0 removed.

So I did eventually discover the answer to this.
What I didn't realize is that the \ used to escape the _ actually needs to be removed in this case.
So:
Occur\<x\>\_\<CON/VAR1/VAR2\>
Covariate\<x\>\_\<CON/VAR1/VAR2\>

becomes:
Occur<x>_<CON/VAR1/VAR2>
Covariate<x>_<CON/VAR1/VAR2>
When rendered as text in the markdown.
